# calculate name of a scoped variable in a repeat control

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat control with an index , let's say comboIndex.
In this repeat control I have a computed field which assigns values to a viewScope lets name it choices followed by the index. So the name of the viewScope is `viewScope.choices0` when the comboIndex has value `0`, `viewScope.choices1` when the comboIndex has value `1` etc.
This viewscope has to be an array and I would like to add elements to it.

I tried :

```
var name = "choices"+comboIndex;
viewScope.put(name,new java.util.Vector());
...
viewScope[name].addElement(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewScope[name]=new java.util.Vector();
```

seems to work ....